# How can i fix node-gyp invalid syntax error for node-20, npm 10 in ionic angular product, Macos ventura 13.3.1

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic-framework, node-gyp, node-sass

`npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js npm ERR! Building: /Users/ashad/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library= npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp verb cli [ npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/ashad/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' npm ERR! gyp verb cli ] npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | darwin | x64 npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild [] npm ERR! gyp verb command clean [] npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory npm ERR! gyp verb command configure [] npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH npm ERR! gyp verb` which`succeeded python2 /usr/local/bin/python2 npm ERR! gyp verb check python version`/usr/local/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.17
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"`returned: %j npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 20.11.0 npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '20.11.0' ] npm ERR! gyp verb install input version string "20.11.0" npm ERR! gyp verb install installing version: 20.11.0 npm ERR! gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed npm ERR! gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion" npm ERR! gyp verb got "installVersion" 9 npm ERR! gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9 npm ERR! gyp verb install version is good npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 20.11.0 npm ERR! gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass/build npm ERR! gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass/build npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file npm ERR! gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi npm ERR! gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi npm ERR! gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi npm ERR! gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make" npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python2 npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/ashad/.node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/common.gypi', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/ashad/.node-gyp/20.11.0', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/ashad/.node-gyp/20.11.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build', npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ] npm ERR! Traceback (most recent call last): npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module> npm ERR!     sys.exit(gyp.script_main()) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main npm ERR!     return main(sys.argv[1:]) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main npm ERR!     return gyp_main(args) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main npm ERR!     options.duplicate_basename_check) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 130, in Load npm ERR!     params['parallel'], params['root_targets']) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 2783, in Load npm ERR!     variables, includes, depth, check, True) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 399, in LoadTargetBuildFile npm ERR!     includes, True, check) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 271, in LoadOneBuildFile npm ERR!     aux_data, includes, check) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 308, in LoadBuildFileIncludesIntoDict npm ERR!     LoadOneBuildFile(include, data, aux_data, None, False, check), npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 251, in LoadOneBuildFile npm ERR!     None) npm ERR!   File "/Users/ashad/.node-gyp/20.11.0/include/node/common.gypi", line 1 npm ERR!     incremental linking npm ERR!                       ^ npm ERR! SyntaxError: invalid syntax npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error  npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error:`gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 22.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/ashad/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/ashad/abdullahSalam/ioniceatonlineapp/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/ashad/.npm/_logs/2024-02-01T09_21_26_284Z-debug-0.log`

I tried to npm install and can not install any npm package after updating node to 20 and npm 10.

Please help me how can i fixed this issues.

I have tried last 3 days but not able to make it fix with node 20, npm 10.

Actually my target to build ionic angular  project into npm 8 or more and node 16 or more.

Note:- with **node v12.22.12 (npm v6.14.16) works fine**